# Plotting epochtime in coreplot

Tags: core-plot, epoch

I am getting data that have epochtime,need to show this epochtime on axis with fixed interval time.I am able to do this thing,but while displaying I need to show only Date not the epochtime.

Code Snippet
long long  xLow = [[[plotData firstObject] objectForKey:@"Time"] longLongValue];
    long long xHigh = [[[plotData lastObject] objectForKey:@"Time"] longLongValue];

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xLow)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xHigh-xLow)];
// Set axis styles
CPTXYAxis *leftY = [(CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet yAxis];
CPTXYAxis *x = [(CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet xAxis];

x.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 6;
long long intervalSize = (xHigh - xLow)/6;
x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromLongLong(intervalSize);
x.majorTickLength = 2.0;
x.minorTickLength = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `labelFormatter` for the axis labels. You can use `CPTTimeFormatter` or `CPTCalendarFormatter` or make your own custom formatter. There is sample code for both built-in formatter classes in the Core Plot example apps.